# Where is the mistake in my code ( Fibonacci)?

Tags: python, function, recursion, output, fibonacci

that is the code (I use python 3):

```
def fibonacci(x):
  if x == 1 or 2:
    return 1
  f = fibonaci(x-1) + fibonaci(x-2) 
  return f

print(fibonacci(4))
```

What I would like to get as an output is 3, which is the fourth Fibonacci number. However I get 1 as an output.

`f = fibonaci(x-1) + fibonaci(x-2)`

I think that code does not do what I want it to do. Lets say I would take `fibonacci(3)` as my input.

What I think should happen:

`f = fibonacci(3-1) + fibonacci(3-2)`

`fibonacci(3-1)` and `fibonacci(3-2)` should both return 1 right? so `f` should be = 2
and `fibonacci(3)` should give me 2 as an output. But what I get as an output is still 1.
Where is the mistake?

Comment: `x == 1 or 2` is always True.

Comment: `f = fibonaci(x-1) + fibonaci(x-2)` ==> `f = fibonacci(x-1) + fibonacci(x-2)`  and it is a slow thing

Comment: @PatrickArtner yup I saw that now as well, thank you. By slow you mean that the code could have been written more efficiently? I just newly got into recursion, maybe I will be able to write it more smartly in the future :D

Comment: dont do recursion.use the linear version without recursion from https://stackoverflow.com/a/499245/7505395 - its much faster and less errorprone. Try yours with fibonaci(100) - the linear version takes under 1s to give you all numbers...

Comment: Will check that out too, thanks ! I was assigned to do this task by recursion, it was only for the purpose of practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in your `if` clause. What you meant was probably this:

```
if x == 1 or x == 2:
```

as `if 2` is always "true", so for any `x` you will be getting `1`.

However, this will still be wrong, as in Fibonacci sequence the first two numbers are `0` and `1`, so:

```
if x <= 1:
    return x
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner I did. If he fixes the clause/return, it should work fine.